# Android save image to file system

Tags: android, camera, android-contentprovider, photo

I have an activity that on start calls an intent to launch the camera app. The camera should take a photo, save to local system, and present it into an imageview. However when the photo is taken I get this message:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_storage_root/Pictures/HelloCamera/IMG_20170709_221239.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

this message is thrown when

```
 final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
            options);
```

inside the previewCapturedImage() method

Here follows the code

I have the following activity

```
package it.cosmopolitans.around.boundary;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import it.cosmopolitans.around.R;

public class ImageTakenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Activity request codes
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public  static final int PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST = 123;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "HelloCamera";

private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

private ImageView imgPreview;
private boolean dir_perm;
private boolean cam_perm;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_taken);

    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTaken);


    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);


    //if(  dir_perm == true )
        captureImage();

    // Checking camera availability
    if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

public void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
}


/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    //return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "it.cosmopolitans.fileprovider", getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean cameraPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if(cameraPermission && readExternalFile)
                    {
                        cam_perm = true;
                        dir_perm = true;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "permission rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }



}
```

I have the following provider in my Manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="it.cosmopolitans.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

And the following file path

```
<external-path name="external_storage_root" path="./"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple but slow solution is to replace:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),  options);
```

with:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri),  options);
```

The two performance improvements you can make:

1. Hold onto the `File` instead of the `Uri`, and then use the `File` with `decodeFile()`
2. Use an image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.), which will do your image-decoding and disk I/O on a background thread

Comment: Thank you it worked! After a little change that is:

    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri));

However i didn't got the second part of your answer. Sorry I'm a newbie in Android. Should i do 1. and 2. together or are those mutually exclusive? In particular I don't understand the first

Comment: @QuasarLex: Should you do both? Ideally, yes, though #2 is more important. With regards to #1, you are holding onto `fileUri` and using that to load the image in. In this case, you know that the image is your own, in a file. It is faster to just do file I/O than it is to go through `FileProvider` to do the same file I/O. However, this requires that you hold onto the `File` from which you get the `Uri`, instead of (or in addition to), the `fileUri` itself.

Comment: @QuasarLex: [FWIW, here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider), showing using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`. In my case, I show the image using an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, instead of loading it into an `ImageView`.